# Google Map Directions API Optimize Waypoint and Force Waypoint Order

Tags: api, google-maps, maps

I am having difficulty in overcoming the situation I am facing. I have a route as follow:

StartPoint

WayPoint A-1 <--- Pickup

WayPoint A-2 <--- Dropoff

WayPoint B-1 <--- Pickup

WayPoint B-2 <--- Dropoff

WayPoint C-1 <--- Pickup

WayPoint C-2 <--- Dropoff

EndPoint

A bus is starting to drive from Start Point and it is supposed to pick 3 passengers up (A, B, C) and drop them off in different locations. The locations are not static and it changes based on passenger.

If I pass all these to google map directions api and set the OptimizeWaypoint option to true the issue that occurs is sometimes the dropoff waypoint occurs before pickup waypoint for a passenger due to route optimization.

Does anyone know a solution to force google map api route optimization to always have pickup before the dropoff for each passenger please?

I appreciate all your help in advance guys.

Comment: You can't do both (Optimize Waypoints and Force Waypoint Order) with the Google Maps API Services.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution to my problem after 3 days of research. The solution is not through Google Map API and it's using a third party API called RouteXL. They are providing an API which does such this thing I am looking for. Here is the link to documentation although their documentation is not clearly documented but it has helped me to work it out.

https://www.routexl.nl/blog/api/?lang=en#post-tour

The function which I needed was the Tour Post and that does what I exactly needed.

If anyone needs any help on this I am happy to help.

I hope this helps everyone else.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Hello @Mohammad, I need your little support, my requirement is also the same as that you mentioned in your description, I am also getting waypoints from API and i need to choose the one which is nearest to my location. The point is i need to draw polyline between all the waypoints based on my current location.

Example : https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8vko8h5121b56q/waypoints.png?dl=0

Comment: I have similar requirement, where there will be multiple pickup and drop off, I collect all points and rendering on direction API but its not rendering properly, showing incorrect addresses on marker and if we remove any point from middle it completely showing mess line

Comment: Hi @Siddharth, sorry for the delay to reply to your comment. Have you found the solution to your issue or you are still stuck please?

Let me know how I can help you if you need me please.

Comment: Hi @dawncode, Could you please let me know what the exact issue is so I can help you? Could you write the code here so I can check where it's going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The waypoint optimization feature in Google Maps is limited to basic travelling salesmen scenarios in which all the waypoints are re-ordered to find the optimal route. What you are looking to do falls under the category of Vehicle Routing problem, more precisely the Vehicle Routing Problem with pickup and delivery. Google doesn't provide a service for this. However, there are some open source algorithm available for this. Here are a few:

- https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/wiki/VRP%20Pickup%20Delivery%20Problem
- https://github.com/graphhopper/jsprit
- https://github.com/mck-/Open-VRP

Most of these use straight line distances to generate a distance matrix between your locations which are then used within the algorithm. For better accuracy you may want to use a distance matrix service that based on travel time. For even more accuracy you may want to take a look at the [Bing Maps distance matrix service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/mt827298.aspx) which also provides the option to generate a distance matrix over a period of time intervals for a day which would fluctuate based on predictive traffic conditions.

Comment: Hi rbrundrutt. Thanks for your help. I have found a better solution to this which I am sending below.